# ASP.NET MVC4 return output from a stored procedure with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, stored-procedures

I been trying to get a simple output from a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getrandomnumber]
        @randoms int output
AS
begin
  set @randoms =12345
end
```

and my mvc

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var qry = db.sp_getrandomnumber(ref randoms); 
      ......
     return View();
    }
}
```

but when I compile I get errors on the `var qry` section saying the following

> No overload for method 'sp_getrandomnumber' takes 1 arguments
>
> The name 'randoms' does not exist in the current context

I tried following this tutorial
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

many thanks in advance
Hesh

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your SPROC output is an int.

See the following quote from Scott Gu's article.

"LINQ to SQL maps "out" parameters in SPROCs as reference parameters (ref keyword), and for value types declares the parameter as nullable."

So you need to make sure you're declaring `randoms` as a nullable int.

Change your sp call to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    // @randoms int output from SPROC.
    int? randoms = null;

    // qry would contain a select if you had one in the SPROC.
    var qry = db.sp_getrandomnumber(ref randoms); 

    // randoms is 12345

    return View();
}
```

Find another example [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/03/13/10236.aspx).