# MVC4 return a stored procedure output with linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a similar issue with thread below [ASP.NET MVC4 return output from a stored procedure with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189527/asp-net-mvc4-return-output-from-a-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework)

I have tried same thing but I am getting the error:

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable on

Here is my procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateValuesInTables]  
(  
    @s_clientid int,
    @success int output
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    Begin Try
        BEGIN TRAN  
            ---- sql statements
        COMMIT TRAN 
        set @success=1 
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        ROLLBACK TRAN  
        set @success=0  
    End Catch
END
```

and c# code

```
int? success = null;
var successCode = Context.usp_UpdateValuesInTables(Convert.ToInt32(obj.SourceClientDropDown),ref success);
```

Why am I getting that error?

If I try to replace `var` with `int` then I am getting error

> Can not implicitly convert type void to int

Comment: If you execute this procedure directly from the SQL server manager is the value returned correctly?

Comment: yes josh.. its returning 1 or 0....

Comment: Assuming Context is the dbDataContext created automatically by linq, have you tried int successCode = Context.usp_UpdateValuesInTables(Convert.ToInt32(obj.SourceClientDropDown),ref success).First().success;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
int? success = null;
Context.usp_UpdateValuesInTables(Convert.ToInt32(obj.SourceClientDropDown),ref success);
var successCode = success; //success is the returned result.
```

Comment: i have tried your code and now i am getting error 'System.Void' is not a valid return type for a mapped stored procedure method.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the Stored Procedure doesn't actually return a value, but Entity Framework isn't aware of the `Void` return.  you need to make sure you use `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the stored procedure so that Entity Framework can determine the `Void` return and map a default value in.

Comment: well when i drag this store procedure to dbml file i get a message that the return type of this store procedure could not be detected.Set the return type of store procedure in property window. Do u think this is problem ??

Comment: you get that message after adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the stored procedure?  your stored procedure as written in the code above never uses the return statement, it relies upon an output variable instead.  However, Entity Framework wants a type to be returned, not an output variable.  using `SET NOCOUNT ON` helps Entity Framework understand that the stored procedure isn't returning anything, only performing actions.