# Get values multi output parameter (stored procedure ) in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

My stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProduct]
    @ProdId int output
    @ProdCode nvarchar(20) output
AS
BEGIN
    SET @ProdId = 1
    SET @ProdCode = 'PROD00001'
END
```

When I call this stored procedure in my action, how to get values of the 2 output parameters `@prodId` and `@ProdCode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put select command in your sp as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProduct]
@ProdId int output
@ProdCode nvarchar(20) output
as
begin
    set @ProdId=1
    set @ProdCode='PROD00001'
    SELECT @ProdId, @ProdCode
end
```

and call this in action like

```
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=yourDbName;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetProduct", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter ProdId = new SqlParameter("@ProdId", SqlDbType.Int);
            ProdId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ProdId);
            SqlParameter ProdCode = new SqlParameter("@ProdCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar,20);
            ProdCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ProdCode);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string ProductCode = (string)cmd.Parameters["@ProdCode"].Value;
            int ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ProdId"].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Nazir. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProduct]
@ProdId int output
@ProdCode nvarchar(20) output
as
begin
    set @ProdId=1
    set @ProdCode='PROD00001'
    select @ProdId,@ProdCode
end
```

Comment: But i want to get this values in Action MVC like : [Link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189527/asp-net-mvc4-return-output-from-a-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework)

Comment: This might help you - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334(v=vs.100).aspx